# glib critical error (gthread) and gtk spinner not showing up

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gtk3, glib

I've a weird problem with distros which are `!(Arch Linux)`.
Actually I'm using Arch Linux with GNOME 3.16 and I've tried my software software with Fedora 22 alpha (GNOME 3.16), Ubuntu and Xubuntu 14.10/15.04 but I always receive the same error:
**`GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID XXX was not found when attempting to remove it`**
I know that the problem is with `g_thread` but I'm not able to understand why I'm not receiving that warning with Arch but only with other distros.
Moreover, the `gtk_spinner` widgets are showing up only on Arch. On Fedora they aren't showing up and I'm not getting any errors...

```
gpointer (*hash_func[NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY])(gpointer) = {compute_md5, compute_gost94, compute_sha1, compute_sha2, compute_sha3, compute_sha2, compute_sha3, compute_sha2, compute_sha3, compute_whirlpool};

struct hash_vars        
{       
    gint n_bit; //number of hash bit (256, 384, 512)
    gboolean gth_created[NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY];
    gchar *filename;    
    GHashTable *hash_table;     
    GtkWidget *hash_entry[NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY]; //md5, gost, sha1, sha256, sha3-256, sha384, sha3_384, sha512, sha3-512, whir     
    GtkWidget *hash_check[NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY]; //md5, gost, sha1, sha256, sha3-256, sha384, sha3_384, sha512, sha3-512, whir 
    GtkWidget *hash_spinner[NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY];
    gchar *key[NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY];
    struct threads_list
    {
        GThread *gth[NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY];
    } threads;

};
```

---

```
    struct hash_vars hash_var;
    /* other things */
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY; i++)
    {
            gtk_widget_set_name (GTK_WIDGET (hash_var.hash_check[i]), bt_names[i]);
            hash_var.gth_created[i] = FALSE;
            g_signal_connect (hash_var.hash_check[i], "clicked", G_CALLBACK (create_thread), &hash_var);
    }
    result = gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    switch (result)
    {
        case GTK_RESPONSE_REJECT:
            for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY; i++)
            {
                if(hash_var.gth_created[i])
                    g_thread_join (hash_var.threads.gth[i]);
            }

            g_free (hash_var.filename);
            g_hash_table_destroy (hash_var.hash_table);
            gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
            break;
    }
}

gpointer
create_thread ( GtkWidget *bt,
                gpointer user_data)
{

    gint i;
    struct hash_vars *hash_var = user_data;
    const gchar *name = gtk_widget_get_name (bt);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_HASH_ENTRY; i++)
    {
        if (g_strcmp0 (name, bt_names[i]) == 0)
        {      hash_var->gth_created[i] = TRUE;
              hash_var->threads.gth[i] = g_thread_new (NULL, (GThreadFunc)hash_func[i], hash_var);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is one of the hash functions:

```
gpointer
compute_md5 (gpointer user_data)
{
    struct hash_vars *hash_var = user_data;

    if (!gtk_toggle_button_get_active (GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON (hash_var->hash_check[0])))
    {
        gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (hash_var->hash_entry[0]), "");
        goto fine;
    }
    else if (g_utf8_strlen (gtk_entry_get_text (GTK_ENTRY (hash_var->hash_entry[0])), -1) == 32)
        goto fine;

    gpointer ptr = g_hash_table_lookup (hash_var->hash_table, hash_var->key[0]);
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        gtk_entry_set_text (GTK_ENTRY (hash_var->hash_entry[0]), (gchar *)g_hash_table_lookup (hash_var->hash_table, hash_var->key[0]));
        goto fine;
    }

    gtk_spinner_start (GTK_SPINNER (hash_var->hash_spinner[0]));

    /* computing md5 */

    fine:
    gtk_spinner_stop (GTK_SPINNER (hash_var->hash_spinner[0]));
    g_thread_exit(NULL);
}
```

So, to summarize, my problems are:

1. I receive a GLib-Critical error only on distro `!(Arch Linux)`
2. `gtk_spinner` are showing up only on Arch

All suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

> "GTK+, however, is not thread safe. You should only use GTK+ and GDK from the thread gtk_init() and gtk_main() were called on. This is usually referred to as the “main thread”."

— https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Threads.html#gdk3-Threads.description

Basically, any time you want to interact with GTK+ you should do it using an idle callback.  That link explains how.

As for why it works on some platforms but not others, it's probably a race condition.